# How do I graph only integers using the list function?

Tags: plotting, integer-sequence

I have plotted the following function using the following code:

```
integers = Table[Integer[n], {n, 20}];
ListPlot[Table[{x, 
x^(-1)*Sum[((6.674*(10^(-11))*(10^17) (4))/((100^2 - 
       400 (2 Cos[(2 Pi k)/x] - 3 Sin[(2 Pi k)/x]) + 
       29)^1.5)), {k, 0, x - 1}]}, {x, integers}]]
```

The function oscillated because it takes values that are not integers. I have searched around and the above does not work. I'm new to mathematica. How can I change the code to make it only use integer values of x?

Comment: Try it with `integers = Range[20]` .

Comment: thanks, another question-where do I put this: AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}

Comment: @OmkarVaidya at the end of ListPlot   after a comma:  ListPlot[...., here]

Comment: @Alucard what if I want to change the range of the function? Perhaps from 3 to 100?

Comment: @OmkarVaidya do you mean the points or the range of the listplot? in the first case write Range[3,100], otherwise add PlotRange->{{yourxmin,yourxmax},{yourymin,yourymax}} after AxesOrigin. don't forget the comma between the 2 options.

Comment: @Alucard thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use[`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html):

```
f[x_] := Sum[((6.674*(10^(-11))*(10^17) (4))/((100^2 - 
         400 (2 Cos[(2 Pi k)/x] - 3 Sin[(2 Pi k)/x]) + 29)^1.5)), {k, 
    0, x - 1}]/x
DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, 1, 20}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the original post has a factor of `x^(-1)` in front of the `Sum`.

Comment: @LouisB thank you. I missed that. I guess it still illustrates use of DiscretePlot. Will change if/when I get time.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot to be said for making code easier to read.  In this case we can write

```
data = Table[{x, x^(-1)*Sum[((6.674*(10^(-11))*(10^17) (4))/((100^2 - 
       400 (2 Cos[(2 Pi k)/x] - 3 Sin[(2 Pi k)/x]) + 
       29)^1.5)), {k, 0, x - 1}]}, {x, 20}];

ListPlot[data]
ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin->{0,25}]
```

Notice that we do not define `integers` because `Table` takes care of that for us.  One advantage of the above is that we can examine our data with

```
data // Dataset
```

and we can add options to our `ListPlot` to build up the command we want.  The optional arguments are added in any order after the required arguments.  They always have the form of rules, like `PlotRange->{All,{25,30}}`

We can see the coordinates of a plotted data point by using `ListPlot[Tooltip[data]]` as the basic command and hovering the mouse pointer over the point whose coordinates we want.

Comment: I also wanted to know how to check the coordinates of a point on the graph. I used the drawing tool, but the y-values of the points are too close to see a difference.

Comment: @OmkarVaidya  I add a paragraph that shows a basic example of how to display the coordinates of a plot data point.  If you search this site for "Tooltip"  you will see some clever examples of how to use this command.

Comment: Thanks for that! The problem is that it only shows 4 decimal places, and all the points show the same value (27.1063). How can i change this?